# How to get all combinations of list of size k (where k > length of the list) in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, combinations, permutation

This prints nothing:

```
from itertools import combinations
comb = combinations([1,2], 3)
for i in comb:
    print(i)
```

I want output as :

```
(1,2,2) (1,2,1) (1,1,2) (1,1,1) (2,1,2) (2,1,1) (2,2,1) (2,2,2)
```

Comment: The reason that using the functions called `combinations` or `permutations` don't give you what you want, and searches for those terms don't get you answers, is that *the things you want are not called combinations*. This is really more of a math terminology question than a programming question.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Seems like you just want the `product`, not `combinations`:

```
from itertools import product

for i in product([1, 2], repeat=3):
    print(i)
```

`combinations` is getting you unique combinations without reusing elements within any combination, which means pulling three elements from two source elements is impossible. It's also order-insensitive, so it wouldn't give you `(1, 2)` and `(2, 1)` even if you only asked for combinations of size `2` (only `permutations` would do that). In your case, you seem to want to cycle every element through every index, allowing repeats (which `combinations`/`permutations` won't do) and order-sensitive (which `combinations_with_replacement` won't do), which leaves `product`.

Answer (score 1):

You can't generate 3 element combinations from a 2 item list. Try this:

```
comb = combinations([1,2]*3, 3)
```

This basically extends the iterable to a 6-item list (`[1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2]`).

Comment: This produces a lot of duplicate outputs (20 total, vs. the OP's desired eight unique outputs).

Comment: Wow this works , the problem is only repetition. But is there any reason that you multiply list [1,2] by **3** and not by anything else ? @Selcuk